# can I use regular green cabbage to make kimchi?

Tags: cabbage

Can regular green cabbage be used for kimchi? I've made several batches with Napa cabbage but it's expensive and not as easily available.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use any cabbage you like.  You can also make kimchi with cucumbers...bean sprouts....really, many vegetables.   It's really just fermenting/pickling.

Comment: Bok Choy makes an excellent addition.

Answer (score 3):

**TR:DR**

**Absolutely.  Use what ever makes you happy.**

The history of kimchi is quite long.  Spanning nearly 2,000 years with many wars between China, Korea, and Japan.  When China and Japan were warring, they would cut through Korea.  The foreigners would bring their local vegetables to feed their troops.  Through many years of conflicts, Korean farmers would take what vegetables they could get their hands on, and ferment them.  Cabbage, radishes, cucumbers, red peppers, and carrots are some of the main ingredients to kimchi.  You can use any type of cabbage for kimchi, if you want to use cabbage at all.  Kimchi is versatile.